# Pretend that site does not exist

Tags: php, cakephp, http-headers, cakephp-2.0, security

I'm interested to know if there's any way to pretend that a site does not exist? I want, for some users, to return an http header (?) or something that will tell the browser that the visited site does not exist.

I was thinking about *444 No Response*, but not really sure.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I can't not response at all, as I should handle other "trusted" users.
At this moment I just calling function `exit;` but I'm not happy with this as "bad users" can use proxy to access the site. In another hand if they will think that site is unavailable it will not try to access it anymore. This is my idea, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: I don't think browsers will report an error code from the server the same as not being able to connect to the server in the first place.

Comment: If you were thinking about sending `444 No response`, did you try it to see if it works?

Comment: The only way to make the site appear not to exist is to *not respond* to the request. At all. The very instant that a connection is made to port 80/443 (and furthermore, when it responds to any HTTP verb) then its "visible". HTTP response codes can only be used to indicate that a *resource within the site* does not exist (or is not accessible, etc). 404 is a great example - the site exist, but the resource (or so it claims) does not exist. However, there are likely more suitable ways to handle "Not Authorized" requests.

Comment: @Barmar no, I didn't try anything yet. Just investigating first if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any response sent back from the server is going to confirm the presence of an http server on the host.

The only way that you are going to be able to hide the existence of the host is by using something like a firewall to swallow any requests and offer no response to the requests that don't meet your access criteria.

If you don't need to hide the existence of the site from an unauthorized party (i.e. they already know there is a site there) you could return a 500 or 404 response to indicate to them that the site is broken or the resource they are trying to get at is not there.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in some of the comments, by the time a script is executed by the webserver, a connection has been made and is known to the client.

However, you may be able to come up with something using port knocking if you really want to dive deep into this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @plenix, it's worth explaining _why_ this is not a good fit for you, otherwise this poster won't have much to respond with. Essentially you need something that will ensure your server does not respond at all in certain circumstances, and this seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a 444 no response via PHP

```
function send444() {
    error_reporting( 0 );
    $status = '444 No Response';
    $protocol = ( isset( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] ) ? substr( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ], 0, 8 ) : 'HTTP/1.1' ) . ' ';
    $header = array(
        $protocol . $status,
        'Status: ' . $status
    );

    foreach ( $header as $sent ) {
        header( $sent );
    }       
    exit();
}
```